# I want to represent date mentioned using angular pipes in CST time zone. i want to convert the given date to CST DATE including daylight savings

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<td>{{document.lastUpdateDateTime | date:"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:a"}}</td>
```

i want to convert the above given date to CST Time zone including daylight savings. Using angular pipes.

i gone through this one.https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

I didnt find CST && Daylight savings here.

```
<td>{{document.lastUpdateDateTime | date:"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:a"}}</td>
```

Is there anything modification in angular pipes which i convert the given timezone to CST && Daylight savings.If daylight savings present it should consider.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just use plain [Javascript Date toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString):

```
lastUpdateDateTime
  .toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/Chicago', ... })
```

I believe the American CST translates to 'America/Chicago` timezone string.

I live in Australia so I'm on GMT+10:00, hence:

[image]

If you want to remove the comma in between date and time and replace "AM" with "am" (or "PM" with "pm"), you can do:

```
lastUpdateDateTime
  .toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/Chicago', ... })
  .replace(',', '')
  .replace('AM', 'am')
  .replace('PM', 'pm')
```

[image]

[You can put that code in your own custom pipe if you want to.](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-pipes-custom-pipes)

Comment: Okay. it will work based up on your solution. Can it support day light saving. As we have DST which will set clock one hour forward/backward during Summer/winter. WIll java script support these??

Comment: <td>{{document.lastUpdateDateTime | date:"MM/dd/yyyy h:mma" :'CST'}}</td>I just added CST in single quotes then it is displaying same as the value storing in date column in database.